# Save as text File without brackets in Spark and change delimiter between the types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I save this `RDD[(String,Double)]` as a text file I get:

```
(Ram is great,1.0)
```

Can I save into file without these brackets and also can we change this comma and put some other delimiter like tab (`\t`).

Hence it will look like:

```
Ram is great    1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Map the RDD to a string with the formatting you prefer.

Something like `coll.map(x=>s"${x._1}\t${x._2}").saveAsTextFile(file)`

Comment: In Python it would be: coll.map(lambda x:"{}\t{}".format(x[0],x[1]))

Answer (score 1):

It will be like this ->

Suppose RDD name is temp

val required = temp.map(f => f._1+"\t"+f._2).saveAsTextFile(path)